# StandOut Android Libarary Examples Crashing

Tags: android, android-logcat

Every time i run the sample floating apps that come with the library the app crashes and i get class not found errors in the logcat. If i remove all refrences to the class in question i simply get a class not found error for another class. Im not sure how to add a logcat so i put it [here](http://pastebin.com/0uWgHnhK). And here is the code for the main class.

```
package wei.mark.example;

import wei.mark.standout.StandOutWindow;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class StandOutExampleActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    StandOutWindow.closeAll(this, SimpleWindow.class);
    StandOutWindow.closeAll(this, MultiWindow.class);
    StandOutWindow.closeAll(this, WidgetsWindow.class);

    // show a MultiWindow, SimpleWindow

    StandOutWindow
            .show(this, SimpleWindow.class, StandOutWindow.DEFAULT_ID);
    StandOutWindow.show(this, MultiWindow.class, StandOutWindow.DEFAULT_ID);
    StandOutWindow.show(this, WidgetsWindow.class,
            StandOutWindow.DEFAULT_ID);

    // show a MostBasicWindow. It is commented out because it does not
    // support closing.


     StandOutWindow.show(this, MostBasicWindow.class,
     StandOutWindow.DEFAULT_ID);


    finish();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason re-importing the library fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

After you import the project, you should add the standOut project as library to standOutExample project. This should not be done by the "auto fixed" from eclipse (it will import the library into java path rather than android path)

The steps to import library project into android project in eclipse:

1. File->New->Other
2. Select Android Project
3. Select "Create Project from existing source"
4. Click "Browse..." button and navigate to standOut project
5. Finish
6. Right-click on standOutExample project -> Properties
7. In Android->Library section click Add
8. select standOut -> Ok